# How to name methods and properties that traverse a tree as akin to moving down through a fully-expanded folder explorer?

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, naming-conventions, naming

Picture a File Explorer-style window with the folders fully expanded. Starting at an arbitrary node, I press the down arrow to move down through the tree. Maybe I'm reading it wrong but I couldn't find a [name for this kind of traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) (note: this article only applies to binary trees; I can't find a good reference on N-ary traversals and their names).

In my code I've struggled to find a good name for this. I've used `GetForwardEnumerator()`, `GetNextNode()`, etc.  The closest I can come to expressing this is that it's the "next node in the tree", but that only makes sense if you look at the tree like a file explorer window as I've described.

What's the standard name for this kind of traversal/enumeration, and how might I name methods and properties that perform it? For now I'm settling for `.NextNode`. It's uncomfortably close to `.NextSibling`, but it's the best way I've found to communicate the intent.

Sample code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the next node.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The next tree node if it exists; otherwise, <c>null</c>.
/// </value>
public SimpleTreeNode<T> NextNode
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            return this.Children[0];
        }
        else if (this.NextSibling != null)
        {
            return this.NextSibling;
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleTreeNode<T> parentNode = this.Parent;
            while (parentNode != null)
            {
                SimpleTreeNode<T> nextSiblingNode = parentNode.NextSibling;
                if (nextSiblingNode != null)
                {
                    return nextSiblingNode;
                }

                parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you're describing is a straightforward in-fix traversal, as explain in the link you cited.

Comment: @nintendojunkie do you mean an in-order traversal? That would imply visiting the left subtree first, plus this is an N-ary tree. That article wasn't the greatest fit I'll admit--it only covers binary trees. Still looking for a good intent-revealing name as applied to this specific kind of N-ary traversal.

Comment: Wow... must have been tired that day.  The answer below is correct - this is a pre-order traversal.  As for binary vs. N-ary trees, the nomenclature is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're talking about Pre-order traversal (so named because the parent is visited before the children).  If you look at the image in the Wikipedia article you reference:

[image: Pre-order Traversal]

The folder-structure equivalent would be:

```
F
|-B
| |-A
| |-D
|   |-C
|   |-E
|-G 
| |-I
|   |-H
```

In a typical fully-open folder structure, the order of traversal is:

1. Visit the parent folder
2. visit the sub-folders in order (recursively)

Which is the definition of [pre-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order).

Comment: OK--I guess `.NextPreOrderNode` or `.NextNodePreOrder` would be fitting property names. Good call, I just didn't get the right tree in mind when I turned my head sideways :)

Comment: PS - For future reference, if you take the time to answer a question, giving the asker an upvote is nice.